# Combobox combinatorics

Tags: vb.net, t-sql, combobox

I have a form with 3 combo boxes. The value of the combo boxes generates a SQL query with 3 parameters. The SQL generates a RDLC report.

For example:

Combox1 with values(v1,v2,v3,ALL)

Combox2 with values(v1,v2,ALL)

Combox3 with values(v1,v2,v3,4,ALL)

```
Me.ExampleTableAdapter.QueryWithParams(Me.ExampleDataSet.Table, Combobox1.SelectedIndex, Combobox2.SelectedIndex,Combobox1.SelectedIndex)
```

QueryWithParams:

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Column1=@c1 AND Column2=@c2 AND Column3=@c3
```

Ok, the problem is when the selected value is ALL in the combo X, I cannot get the values because I must change the query and kick out the parameter.
For example:
If the combo1, combo2, combo3 have the values ALL. I don't need parameters.

```
SELECT * FROM Table
```

If the combo1 is ALL.

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Column2=@c2 AND Column3=@c3
```

If combo1 and combo3 are ALL

```
SELECT* FROM Table WHERE Column2=@c2
```

...
Then in code I look which is the selected value of the combo and upon it I do the query.

Is there a way that i do this thing **without generating all** 8 types of queries?

PS. I cannot use stored procedures because I'm using SQL Server Compact

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the value for 'ALL' should be sent to the query with value 'NULL'

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table 
WHERE (Column1=@c1 OR @c1 IS NULL)
AND (Column2=@c2 OR @c2 IS NULL)
AND (Column3=@c3 OR @c3 IS NULL)
```

Edit:
Of course same can be done for any specified 'ALL'-value
Example of 'ALL' = -1

```
(Column1=@c1 OR @c1 = -1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be a ble to use IsNull in your query for the columns where nothing/all was selected:

```
WHERE Column1 = ISNULL(@c1, Column1)
```

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms184325.aspx)